# How to detect the height of onscreen keyboard in iphone/ipad using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I want to know the height of onscreen keyboard in iphone/ipad for chatting application.
I am able to detect whether the device is IOS using this code:

```
var iOS = !!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);
```

I did some search and found few similar questions but none of them worked for me. Is there some code that works for all IOS devices.

**Edit:**
The reason behind my question is that I want to find out the remaining area of body after the keyboard is opened. Unlike android devices, in iOS, the virtual keyboard's presence does not change the viewport height.

Comment: I'm really interested in an answer as well! I tried it in React JS with this one https://github.com/mvasin/react-div-100vh. But it doesn't calculate the height of the keyboard into account. It's just the whole height of the screen, so a scrollbar appears. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: There is even a Medium article about it: https://blog.opendigerati.com/the-eccentric-ways-of-ios-safari-with-the-keyboard-b5aa3f34228d

Answer (score -2):

First of, you want to detect the iPhone/iPad device rotation, then you want the code to detect the ios version, and the type of device (eg. iPad 2). Then you want to search the average pixel for the keyboard (more specifically: the device model.) then tell it in your javascript, to set the value to whatever you are working on to say: if the ipad is the ipad 2, set the keyboard to 0x0 <--- insert pixel there.  Hope I was a help.